# Is there a way to point scaladoc index.html to my specific package?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I'm trying to build a nice scaladoc, and I found one problem though - index.html points to root package, which does not make any sense as all of my classes obviously not there, and to actually start reading about whatever I did person will need to browse to my package first and only then it'd be possible to actually start to get knowledge.

I looked into settings for scaladoc in scala.tools.nsc.doc.Settings and only option which seems suitable is doc-root-content. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you want to publish your scaladoc? If i am getting you right?
If this is the case then i did it using gitlab-ci.yml once. I moved all my files to gitlab server and in my wiki pages i provided the path to my index.html path on gitlab server.

Comment: Yes, that's for publishing. Thank you. This change will do the job, but solution doesn't feel like a good one. I'd rather have some configuration option to point to my starting package or something like this.